# Expo startLocationUpdatesAsync doesn't work on android 8.0 + when minimized

Tags: react-native, expo

Hey I have a problem with expo latest TaskManager featur. I'm trying to implement background user locating while application is in background. Firstly, expo API background location works perfectly on Android Version 5.0 and 6.0. But on versions 7.0+, when i minimazie application gps service is paused. It's probably due to android battery saving. Do you guys know any workarounds?

Comment: Hey @Kendzior, were you able to solve this issue?